# jQuery traversing dom to get to an element

Tags: jquery

I am having a hard time figuring out how to correctly and most efficiently traverse the DOM to select the element I need.

Basically I need it where when the select statement is changed, it would change an element's CSS to display block.  Initially it is display NONE.

I currently am trying to use `prevAll()` but obviously it isn't working...

Please see https://jsfiddle.net/8G4Aj/ for live sample

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="more-wrapper">
        <img src="http://someimage.png" alt="image" />
    </div>    
</div>

<div class="another-wrapper">
    <div class="some-wrapper">
        <form>
            <select>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("form select").change(function() {
    $(this).prevAll('img').css("display","block");
});
```

Comment: prevAll only includes sibling elements, and doesn't traverse up or down the hierachy. It seems like a convoluted example - why don't you just use a simple selector to select the image you know you want?

Comment: do you have only one image tag to display block?? or based on the value in the dropdown list u want to display any image tag? here is an example that works not sure if u want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/8G4Aj/2/

Comment: There will be whole bunch of images so I have to traverse it in context to THIS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help wondering if you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. It SEEMS like a case where some additional classes could help.

But, I failed to create that sort of scenario. So I did this instead:

https://jsfiddle.net/8G4Aj/4/

```
$("form select").change(function() {
    $(this).closest('.another-wrapper').prev().find('img').css("display","block");
});
```

Up the tree to `another-wrapper` then to its previous sibling (`wrapper`), then dig back into that div for the image.

Comment: Thanks for this and unfortunately it is this complicated because this will serve as a plugin to another site where I can't simply add a class to their elements and there will be multiple of these containers.

Comment: Glad it helps. I was concentrating on the traversal, but as others have pointed out, you can also use `.show()` rather than `.css("display", "block")`

Answer (score 1):

You need a selector that gets to the image you're trying to hide.  `prevAll()` only looks at siblings before the starting element.  You don't have any images that match that.

In the HTML you have in your jsFiddle, you could use this:

```
$("form select").change(function() {
    $(".more-wrapper img").show();
});
```

Much better that this if there's just one image would be to put an ID on the desired image so you can target it directly.

If this is a pattern that you use multiple places in the same page, then you can make one body of code that will work in all of them if you give the image a unique class and put both image and form in a common parent div with a common class name.  That would look like this:

Code:

```
$("form select").change(function() {
    $(this).closest(".formSet").find(".toggleImage").show();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="formSet">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="more-wrapper">
            <img class="toggleImage" src="http://someimage.png" alt="image" />
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="another-wrapper">
        <div class="some-wrapper">
            <form>
                <select>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S.  `.show()` is a shortcut for setting `display: block;`

Comment: I like this one, too. Matches my suspicion that the original was unecessarily complex. Although it only saves one DOM traversal activity vs. mine, it also allows you to style and target other things in the `formset` in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the jQuery [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/), and [show](https://api.jquery.com/show/) functions?

```
$("div.some-wrapper select").change(function() { 
   $("div.more-wrapper  img").show(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this https://jsfiddle.net/nicosunshine/8G4Aj/3/

The problem you had is that youre trying to get the images in the context of the select ( in your case `$(this)` ), so I changed that selector to  `$(".wrapper")` so it grabs the top element that contains the img and then use find to get the img.

You can do that in other ways too, for example you could put an id in the img, and then change

```
$(".wrapper").find('img').css("display","block"); //gets the div with the class wrapper and finds the images that it contains and changes the css
```

to

```
$("#imgID").css("display","block"); //grabs the element with the id of imgID and changes the css
```

witch will be more efficient, like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nicosunshine/8G4Aj/5/)

Comment: Although the original question wasn't clear, I think there are going to be multiple forms with the same HTML pattern. This solution won't work because it tightly couples the change function to a specific ID.

Comment: Aw, you're right. I read "correctly and most efficiently" and the first thing that pops is "ID!!"